# Cannot read special characters from the filename

Tags: java, linux, encoding

I have a situation where linux mounted NAS includes filenames which has Scandinavian characters like ä, ö, å. When I list files with ls I see all those characters as question marks (?). If I run ls -b I will see encoded version of filename. Characters like this: \303\205

I need to read those **files and their filenames** from my Java code but I'm not able to. If I use File.listFiles to list files I'm getting question marks instead of correct characters. If I convert File to Path I'm getting exception:
*java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters*
I' able to get rid of the exception, if I set Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 when running it, but then again I get question marks instead of ä,ö or å.

I tried to mount NAS different with settings like check=relaxed but not luck there.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you print the *numeric* character values of a filename you get without exception using the Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 and add this to your question, together with the correct filename?

Comment: It's a bad thing already if "ls" doesn't properly show the file names. Have you set your (system default) encoding to UTF-8? If not, java can't help that. (I assume the NAS uses UTF-8, otherwise it will be more complicated).

Comment: If I login to the server with Mac Cyberduck and go to mount I can see right characters...

Comment: What do you see when you `System.out.println( "\u00E4\u00E5\u00F6" );` ?

Comment: When I run System.out.println( "\u00E4\u00E5\u00F6" ); I see ???

Comment: Then the problem is your local (system default) encoding. These escapes produce äåö, and you should see them like that in an xterm. So the problem has nothing to do with NAS. If you do that other test I proposed the output should show the decimal equivalents of these hex numbers.

Comment: In that shell, enter `LANG=en_US.utf-8` and then run the Java program once more.

Comment: It's already that and does not work. I tried to run java with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 and System.out.println looks correct, but when printing out filename chars are ����

Comment: How can it be utf-8 and not display  "\u00E4\u00E5\u00F6" correctly? If I enter LANG=en_US.iso-8859-1 and run this program, I get ??? too.

Comment: So please print the individual characters of such a filename in decimal and add it to your Q, together with the correct letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved this one. If I login from the Linux to the server, which I use to run the code, it DOES NOT set LC_CTYPE, BUT if I login with my MAC it DOES set it UTF-8. So how application works on the server is dependent on the SSH client I use to run it....